# accessing session object in html 5

Tags: javascript, html, session

I would like to know - how to implement a login in HTML5 where I want Login to be shown if session doesn't exists on first load and if any session with user data exists i want 'name' to be displayed instead of 'login'.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manage sessions without a server side language like PHP, Ruby, etc. HTML5 and JavaScript can only manage things on the user's side.

Comment: Yea that's what I want to know if there is any way I can implement any servlet  to check session through javascript. I am using. What's the code I need to use for calling a session object through javascript or if possible directly on HTML5 page

Comment: You can use `cookies`: see W3:
 https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should look at HTML5 Local Storage
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp first. If this is not what you want then you have to use a server side language.

For using session object for login, you can do something like(PHP example):

1.Store the user's details in session object when user logs in via **xyz.com/login**

```
$_SESSION["username"] = "username";
```

2.When the user visits xyz.com next time, check if a value of a session object already exists.

```
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    // redirect to user profile etc.
}
else{
    // show login page - xyz.com/login
}
```

For more info: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp